# SwiftUI automatic refresh of Coudkit data

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit

I'm using CloudKit to store my data but now I have to close the app every time something changed. With @FetchRequest this should be automatic, shouldn't it?

```
@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Exercise.createdAt, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)

private var exercises: FetchedResults<Exercise>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your have enabled Push and remote notifications per the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit)

```
Project Settings > Signing and Capabilities
```

[Sync CoreData with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/syncing_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit) using

```
try? persistentContainer.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
```

Comment: Yes, I have already turned that option on.

Comment: Try syncing with CloudKit

Comment: What is .current? I get the Following error -> Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'current'

Comment: NSQueryGenerationToken https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsquerygenerationtoken

Comment: Make sure you put it in after loading the store